# Line break not working with jQuery .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, key-value, line-breaks

I have the following code:-

```
function data(x) {
     var dataList = "";
     for (var key in obj) {
          dataList += key + ": " + obj[key] + "\n"
     }
     $('#modalText').text(dataList);
     document.getElementById('dataModal').style.display='block';
}
```

And it populates the HTML like this:

```
<p id="dataList"></p>
```

Although I have a '\n' concatenated to my string with each iteration of the loop, I cannot get the line break after each key/value pair to show in my modal. I have also tried the jQuery .append() function instead of .text(), to no avail.

My variable, dataList, prints in the console with proper line breaks, like this:

```
key: 123
time: 12:00
department: taxes
```

But when printed in the modal, there are no line breaks:

```
key: 123 time: 12:00 department: taxes
```

How can I get it to show in my modal with a new line break after each key-value pair, as it shows in the console?

Comment: Try typing a line break into the raw HTML; you'll see that it doesn't show up when shown in a browser. Same deal when added via script.

Comment: In a modal, there won't be a line break via a newline character -- the contents of a modal (unless it's a textarea) will be pure HTML and newlines aren't. Is there a reason you aren't using .html() instead of .text() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whitespace means nothing in HTML. You need to either use `<br/>` and set the `.html()`, or you need to add a `white-space: pre` to your dataList `<p>` tag. Using `pre` or `pre-wrap` will respect whitespace (and therefore \n characters)

Comment: Totally agreed with you!

Comment: This is perfect thank you! I used the combination of <br> and .html()

Comment: @kss please note that if your `dataList` properties will contain html tags or entities the result won't be good because they will be treated as HTML. In your case `white-space:pre` is probably better and more secure solution.

Comment: @kss Just be mindful that every time you set the `.html()` of something, you are potentially vulnerable to script injection. Unless you are absolutely sure that the data can't be corrupted with harmful scripts, I would stay away from setting HTML (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

simply `<br>`is sufficient  to get line break rather "/n" as shown in below code.

```
 function data(x) {
 var dataList = "";
 for (var key in obj) {
      dataList += key + ": " + obj[key] + "<br>"
 }
 $('#modalText').text(dataList);
 document.getElementById('dataModal').style.display='block';
```

}

Comment: ^This still needs .html() instead of .text()